# The meaning of “that” in “. . . and that enabling it does . . .”

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I'm not sure about the meaning of the word “**that**” in this paragraph:

> TruPrevent behavior-based malware detection was once a big selling
>   point for Panda, so I was somewhat surprised to find it turned off by
>   default. My Panda contact explained that advances in other technology
>   have made TruPrevent less necessary, and **that** enabling it does
>   consume a bit more of the system's resources.
>   
> <sub>Source: [PC Mag, Panda Antivirus Pro 2014](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2429593,00.asp)</sub>

I guess “and **that**” can be replaced with “and **therefore**” or “and **consequently**” or “and **so**”. Am I right? Is the word “**that**” somehow related to grammar in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word “that” introduces the second thing that was explained. Technically speaking, it is a conjugation that introduces a subordinate clause. The sentence can be broken down:

> My Panda contact explained . . .
>
> 1. **that** advances in other technology have made TruPrevent less necessary and
> 2. **that** enabling it does consume a bit more of the system's resources

Some people would say it this way (not reading the numbers):

> My Panda contact explained **that** . . .
>
> 1. advances in other technology have made TruPrevent less necessary and
> 2. enabling it does consume a bit more of the system's resources

It's a two-item list, written out. The instance of “that” that you've highlighted is optional, but helps the person reading or listening mark the transition to the second item and remember the attached verb “explain”.

Phrased as they are, the two items aren't really related to one another (other than the fact that they are both explanations offered for TruPrevent being disabled by default), so I wouldn't recommend any of the replacements you suggest.

The *implied* message is that the events described in the first item reduce the benefit provided by the TruPrevent below a reasonable value, given the cost to system resources mentioned in the second item. As it's currently written, we're left to draw that conclusion on our own, but it *could* be written:

> My Panda contact explained that advances in other technology have made it so **that** enabling TruPrevent is no longer worth consuming more of the system's resources.

In this rewording, “that” functions more along the lines of the other words you suggest.